# jQuery plugin that makes IE render css properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I recently stumbled upon a jQuery plugin that was supposed to force IE to render properly.  I can't remember what it was called.

Does anybody know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about jquery plugin but you might want to go for popular [`IE7.js`](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/):

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer behave
>   like a standards-compliant browser. It
>   fixes many HTML and CSS issues and
>   makes transparent PNG work correctly
>   under IE5 and IE6.

Comment: Sounds pretty good.  I feel like this is a better fix than making a separate CSS file...

Comment: @Kevin Brown: I  personally use that, a lot easier than other hacks.